# How to rewrite 302 location

Tags: moovweb

There is a 302 from proxying the site locally which goes to something like `http://externalsite.com/foo?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myproject.com` which then does a 302 to `http://www.myproject.com`. It's because of the query parameter so how can I rewrite that?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**
So check out this example I made up using the Tritium Tester: http://play.tritium.io/b3f66d045f25e6669c1587e5469f1475d4fec0b8

I think it will help.

**Explanation**

Basically, you can open the `url()` scope and then you have access to functions to adjust the query parameters such as `param()` which is a parameter "gettor" and then `remove_param()` which will strip it out.

Once you've got the URL looking how you want, you can just set the Location header to that URL using the `export()` function:

`export("Location", $new_url)`